# Difference between two scaled normal distribution CDFs

Tags: calculus, normal-distribution

If $\Phi$ is the CDF of the standard normal distribution, then I have the following equation, which I'm trying to solve for $x$:

$a\Phi(x)=1-\Phi(x+b)$,

where $a$ and $b$ are real, positive constants.

I tried writing out the actual integral over $\varphi$, of the form $\int_{-\infty}^{x}e^{-(t-b)^2}dt$ but then you end up with a term of the for $e^{2bt}$ inside the integral.

Is the above equation actually solvable? (E.g. under the special case of $b=0$, the solution becomes $x=\Phi^{-1}\left( \frac{1}{a+1} \right)$.) If it is: how? If it isn't: why not?

Comment: It is solvable in the sense that there is a unique real solution, but I would be surprised if there was a general closed form solution

Comment: @Henry: I agree that there has to be a unique real solution: the left hand side goes up from 0 to a, and the right hand side goes down from 1 to 0, so the two must be equal exactly once (as long as a is positive). I would guess that there is no closed-form solution, but I can't exactly show it.